# EtherCAT Half/Full-Duplex?

Tags: ethercat

When using a ET1100 and two PHY I noticed on the TMS320F28388d control card that one of the PHY is configured in Half-Duplex (pull up/down on the COL pin).

It would be good to take a look at the TMDSECATCNCD379D schematics, but it is not available.

Is there any reason why both PHY are not similar?

[image]

Comment: I had an controlSUITE installation (v3.4.9 - March 28, 2018). There is a ``controlSUITE/development_kits/TMDSECATCND379D_V1.0/HWDevpkg/design.zip`` file, and inside the zip a ``design/logic/TIDM-DELFINO-ETHERCAT_SCH.pdf`` schematic. Is that enough for you to find the TMDSECATCNCD379D schematics? The schematic shows two ``DP83822`` phys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The COL/GPIO2 pin sets the PHY address.

As you cannot have two PHYs with same address on the MDIO bus, they need to be set into two different addresses as per the schematics.

This in no way sets or affects the duplex mode of the PHY.